# Define function with property f(a,b,c) = f(c,a,b) = f(b,c,a)

Tags: function, substitution, maple

Is it possible in Maple to define a function (or operator) with property f(a,b,c) = f(c,a,b) = f(b,c,a), but not necessary other cases like f(a,b,c) = f(a,c,b).
In Maple it should work like this:

```
[> f(a,b,c)-f(c,a,b), f(a,b,c)-f(b,c,a), f(a,b,c)-f(a,c,b);
                   0, 0, f(a,b,c)-f(a,c,b)
```

That is, function f could be non symmetric, but it shouldn't change under the substitution [a=b,b=c,c=a]:

```
[> f(a,b,c)-subs([a=b,b=c,c=a],f(a,b,c));
                   0
```

Just to make it clear: the question isn't about giving an example of such function, but about defining such property of function f in Maple, so that it would work as described (Maple would simplify the expression f(a,b,c)-f(c,a,b) to zero for any a,b,c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't offhand see a way to accomplish this using just the `define` command. But there are alternative mechanisms.

One of the tricky aspects involves getting Maple's `-` (minus) to discern the equivalence while still allowing all calls to `f` to return unevaluated with the original order of arguments.

Relaxing that aspect for the time being, here's one easy idea. Devise `f` such that it rotates the arguments into a canonical order. The precise nature of the canonicalization may not matter -- here I happen to rotate according to the position of the entry with smallest memory address, but I could also have devised it with a lexicographic measurement.

```
restart;

f:=proc(x,y,z)
  local addr,i,m;
  addr:=map(:-addressof,[x,y,z]);
  m:=min[':-index'](addr);
  'procname'([x,y,z][[seq(`if`(m+i>3,(m+i) mod 3,
                               m+i),i=0..2)]][]);
end proc:

f(a,b,c)-f(c,a,b), f(a,b,c)-f(b,c,a), f(a,b,c)-f(a,c,b);

             0, 0, f(a, b, c) - f(a, c, b)
```

That gets the results you described, as a consequence of the following behavior.

```
f(a,b,c), f(b,c,a), f(c,a,b);

           f(a, b, c), f(a, b, c), f(a, b, c)

f(a,c,b), f(b,a,c), f(c,b,a);

           f(a, c, b), f(a, c, b), f(a, c, b)
```

You can see that the call `f(c,b,a)` actually returns the result `f(a,c,b)`. Now, it's possible that you would also desire that,

```
f(a,b,c) - f(c,b,a)
```

returns as *exactly* that same expression. But the code above will return it as `f(a,b,c) - f(a,c,b)`. If that is a problem for you then let me know. I can envision two other mechanisms, which involve changing how `-` works.

The first is to rebind `-` to be procedure that can inspect the calls to `f`, while still returning them unevaluated (identical to the inputs) if they don't cancel each other arithmetically. This would just affect `-` when *you* call it from the top level. It wouldn't always affect how `-` works when called within other stock Library commands.

Another way would be to construct the calls to `f` as `objects` which export their own static `-` method.